# Using ActiveRecord enum give error about generating 'new' class method on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

I am using `ActiveRecord` *enums* in my Rails app that is version **4.1.4**. I have a enum on the `status` column of my `Message` model.  When I attempt to use the helper method `statuses` to see all of the available statuses I get the error: *You tried to define an enum named "status" on the model "Message", but this will generate a class method "new", which is already defined by Active Record.*

The `Message` model `belongs_to` two other models, but that isn't the issue because I commented out the relationship and it still presented the error.  I cannot seem to find anyone else having this issue.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contact
  enum status: %w(new assigned archived)
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Wow I really wasnt thinking here, I was attempting to use the enum value `new` which is a class method so I therefore cannot define a new method using `enum status: [:new]`.  I just had to change it to *unassigned*

Comment: Yup the text says it iself, it is a matter of interpretation.